# Footnote after the table and not before

Tags: tables, footnotes

I manage show the footnotes inside table using savenotes and charging `\usepackage{footnote}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{section1}

\blindtext
\blindtext\footnote{footnote outside table}
\blindtext

\begin{savenotes}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{6cm}}
\hline \hline
element11  & element12\footnote{footnote inside table}    \\ \hline 
element21  & element 22   \\ \hline 
\blindtext  &\blindtext   \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Title}
\label{table_ref1}
\end{table}
\end{savenotes}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The problem with that is that many times the footnote appear on the page before the one with the table... How can I change that ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `footmisc` package with the option `bottom`?

Comment: I edited with compilable exemple, in which footnote go before the text.

Comment: I also tried loading the footmisc package with the option bottom, adding  '\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}', but nothing changes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the utmost in power and flexibility, in terms of creating and displaying footnotes inside a table, consider loading the `threeparttable` package, using `\tnote` directives to insert footnote markers where needed, and using the package's `tablenotes` environment to display the footnotes.

Two nice little side benefits of using the machinery of the `threeparttable` package are (a) footnote markers may be repeated and (b) you're not limited to any particular footnote style; it's perfectly possible to mix numbers, letters, and symbols as footnote markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Title}
\label{table_ref1}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll} \toprule 
element11  & element12\tnote{a} \\ \addlinespace 
element21\tnote{$\dagger$} & element22\tnote{a}  \\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\medskip % some vertical separation
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize  % nothing is optional in 'tablenotes'
\item[a] a repeated footnote
\item[$\dagger$] another footnote
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```